# remove all calendar icon for input disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use in my page some datepickers for each input who needs it,

but sometimes, somefields are disabled.

I would like to remove all calendar and there datepicker icon if the inputs are disabled

I've tried something like that

```
if($(".datepicker").prop('disabled')){
   $(this).removeClass('datepicker');
}
```

in a document.ready function, etc...

but it does not work

also, the datepicker icon has a a specific class

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="images/calendar-day.png" alt="..." title="...">
```

all I need is to remove that picture for all input disabled because, with that icon users can open datepicker and change the date.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle of your problem, would be easier and faster to help you that way.

Comment: Try $('img.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS rule:

```
input.hasDatepicker[disabled] + img.ui-datepicker-trigger {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: it works fine, thank you so much for your help I'll be able to accept this answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -

```
$(".datepicker").each(function(){
   if($(this).prop('disabled')){
      $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: As i see it, `ui-datepicker-trigger` is not child of `.datepicker`

Comment: to the selector I guess ?